# Sheet.getRange throwing signature mismatch exception when not using A1 notation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, method-signature

I'm writing a script on a Google Sheet that will be interacting with Google Map's Geocoding service.

The following code works correctly.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var header_v = ss.getRange("1:1").getValues();
```

However, later on in my function, I call `Sheet.getRange()` again using the `Sheet.getRange(number, number, number, number)` method:

```
var target_range = ss.getRange(1, ss.getLastColumn()+1, ss.getLastRow(), 10);
```

throws the following exception:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for Spreadsheet.getRange.

I've tried substituting the first parameter with a variable I know to be a number, to the same effect.

This is the function in its current state.

```
function geocode() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var header_v = ss.getRange("1:1").getValues();
  
  var col_indxs = {
    name : header_v[0].indexOf("restaurant_name"),
    address : header_v[0].indexOf("address")
  }

  var target_range = ss.getRange(1, ss.getLastColumn()+1, ss.getLastRow(), 10);
  Logger.log(target_range.getA1Notation());
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Resolved this myself.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Returns a `Spreadsheet`, however the `getRange(number, number, number, number)` is a member of the `Sheet` class.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: getRange is also a method of spreadsheet class but with a different signature.

Comment: thanks! this was such a gotcha! :O I wonder why on earth they would they keep the getRange() methods in both classes and not consistently keep them in sync with each other?

Comment: @Magne Calling `getRange()` from the File level compared to the Sheet level is a very different operation. You have to specify the Sheet when calling `getRange()` from the file level. It would be absurd if the application itself randomly chose a sheet to operate on. Hence the two functions cannot be kept in sync with eachother because they operate with different context.

Comment: An improvement I would like to see on Google's part is a pointer in the generic error message to help coders identify the problem: it is not a syntax problem, it is a problem with context.

Comment: You can directly do this, `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` (no need to chain it with `getActiveSpreadsheet`)

Comment: Even still, why is it erroneously calling a number a string?